# AWS Python Boto3 - Getting an instance running time by id

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

I'm trying to find the number of minutes an instance has been up using the python boto3 library for aws. I'm not able to find a direct way to do this. I can get the status of a machine using:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)

status = instance.state['Name']
print(status)
```

But what I'm looking for is a simple metric: The number of minutes an instance has been running. Note that this is not the uptime of an instance as it gets reset whenever it is stopped.

Comment: Not clear. Are you looking for launch time (when the instance was created) or uptime (when the instance was last started).

Comment: I generally calculate the ENI attachment time. It is very rare that users attach / detach ENI. There is no 1 command to identify the instance creation time. AWS provides the uptime only (when the instance was last started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating another lambda function that runs every minute and if the instance is running, it increments the value stored in dynamodb. Not a great solution but this works well.

```
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com")
    table = dynamodb.Table('<table name>')

    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']

    for i in data:
        state = get_state(i['instance_id'])
        if (state=='running'):
            response = table.update_item(
                Key={
                'id': i['id']
                },
                UpdateExpression="set runTime = :r",
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':r': i['runTime'] + 1,
                },
                ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
            )

    return response

def get_state(instance_id):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
    return instance.state['Name']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea which you could try. Query CloudTrail data for "RunInstance
", "StopInstance" and "StartInstance" calculate the total running time of the instance.

Here is the script I have created.
https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/990dbb67f397d79556dbc02e5835e5ec

Sample output:

```
i-0xxxxxfcd40ebd6a1 user 0:09:21.263278
i-xxxxxx502450c96aa yser 84 days, 15:13:37.651975
i-xxxxxxfcdf27ec894 yser 6 days, 15:43:52.191147
i-xxxxx386c630af322 user 13 days, 14:08:49.429469
i-xxxxxxxd41bf975eb test 21:37:59.67100
```

Comment: It doesn't handle the time when the instance is stopped. It seems to only handle when the instance was first created.

Comment: it calculates all the start and stop time not based on launch time. may be there is bug, I havent tested it fully.

Comment: and its an idea, you might want to improvise further.

Comment: It actually works, what considerations does it further need @SudharsanSivasankaran?